# Google Maps Distance/Duration Markers & Labels

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

On this screenshot of Google Maps, you can see the Duration of the drive and the distance, for both the main route and the alternative one, and the textual labels for the destination (Knutsford Golf Club).

[image]

I'm using the Google Maps API and have added the route and alternate route but I'm unable to find anything in the documentation about these distance/duration markers and the textual labels.

Are they possible to recreate in any sensible way or are they something for only Google?

Answer (score 0):

They are controlled by google by default. When you do a directions request, you can remove the markers by using `supressMarkers` property

```
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(
  {
      suppressMarkers: true
  });
```

Reference: [Directions Renderer Options](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions)

Directions request does provide with all values for turn by turn navigation.

**Additionally:** You can add all the default markers of directionRenderer by yourself on the map, controlling the way in which you want.

```
directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
   directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(
  {
      suppressMarkers: true
  });
```

All the steps of the direction service can be found in `directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs[0].steps` which gives the content of info windows and position of the markers as displayed on map.

You will have multiple `routes`, if available and multiple `legs` if there are waypoints present.

Do a `console.log(directionsDisplay)` and further explore the result object.

Comment: I don't think these are step by step directions though, they're just stating how long each route would take and the difference in alternate routes (2 min slower). Also I'm not sure though are the info windows as they're very different, and positioning the arrows would be quite the nightmare. Unless I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: They do contain all the steps of the travel. It is from this result that google itself shows the direction text for navigation

Comment: Sorry, I mean - what you've illustrated is the steps, but I don't think that's what I need. In the screenshot, those don't look like steps but rather a route time. I could add up all the durations in the steps but that doesn't get me these kind of visual labels on the map.

Comment: You get the `travel_mode` and `distance`, `duration` all under `steps`. Based on `travel_mode` and `transit` you can add your own custom infowindows and markers.